# Images are not showing in node js and heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, handlebars.js

I've deployed my node js app to Heroku, and everything seems to work perfect except static image files.

I've tested locally with

> heroku local web

and the images are working correctly, but not when I check in heroku.
I'm working with node.js, express and handlebars for templates. This is the project structure.
Images are located in public/imagenes/

and my views in views/

[image: file structure]

And this is the code of the login.hbs file that it's not showing the images.

```
    <div class="login-page">
  <div class="form">
    <form class="register-form" name="register" method="POST" action="/register_success">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required/>
      <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="nombre"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Crear cuenta" name="register_success"></input>
      <p class="message">Ya registrado? <a href="#">Entrar</a></p>
      <img src="../public/imagenes/YupiLogo.png" alt="Logo Yupi" width="15%" id="cabecera"/>
    </form>
    <form class="login-form" name="login" method="POST" action="/login">
      <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="email" required/>
      <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required/>
      <input type="submit" value="Login" name="login"/>
      <p class="message">No registrado? <a href="#">Crea una cuenta</a></p>
      <img src="imagenes/YupiLogo.png" alt="Logo Yupi" width="15%" id="cabecera"/>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
$('.message a').click(function(){
    $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
});
});
</script>
```

You can check the app in heroku at [heroku node app](https://yupee.herokuapp.com/)

Attached network request for images.
[image: network request for images]

Answer (score 0):

I had look at [Heroku app](https://yupee.herokuapp.com/), it throws error of 404 for images as it is not possible for it to find path of images.

To make application able to find path, please add following statement into your main .js file

```
app.use(express.static('public/imagenes'));
```

and provide image name into src as following,

```
<img src="YupiLogo.png" alt="Logo Yupi" width="15%" id="cabecera"/>
```

Comment: Thanks Vikas. That's not explaining the fact that I can see the images with heroku local web. Let me say that my file already contained app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

Comment: Run copy of working code in local and capture network requests for images. Please provide that screenshot of network requests?

Comment: Updated. Not sure if this is what you need. Thanks.

Comment: Not this part, I want url and header part